# 3 Seconds jQuery counter

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

My JS code:

```
 var counter = 3;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {counter--;  if (counter == 0) {clearInterval(interval);}}, 1000);

    $('#msg').hide().html('Page will refresh in ' + timer).slideDown('fast');
```

Why is it not working? 
This is the reply I get: "Page will refresh in 14522"

All I am trying to make 3 second countdown. I don't want any actions after that. So what is the problem?Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to show `counter` on the screen, not `timer`. Second, you need to update the message every time your counter changes:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    $('#msg').html('Page will refresh in ' + counter);
    if (counter == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```